# How to set upstream proxies for each request in Titanium Web Proxy

Tags: .net, proxy

We are using [Titanium Web Proxy](https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy) to crawl certain sites:

```
ProxyServer proxyServer = new ProxyServer();;
        proxyServer.BeforeRequest += OnRequest;
        proxyServer.BeforeResponse += OnResponse;
        proxyServer.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += OnCertificateValidation;
        proxyServer.ClientCertificateSelectionCallback += OnCertificateSelection;
        proxyServer.ConnectionTimeOutSeconds = 30;
        proxyServer.AddEndPoint(explicitEndPoint);
        proxyServer.UpStreamHttpProxy = new ExternalProxy() 
         { 
           \\ params here 
         }
        proxyServer.Start();
```

This lines sets up upstream proxy for all requests:

```
proxyServer.UpStreamHttpProxy = ...
```

but I need to set up different UpStreamHttpProxy for each upstream request. I don't seem to be able to accomplish this. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. Take a look here: [How to use different ExternalProxy for each https request ?](https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy/issues/313)

This is the API:
[GetCustomUpStreamProxyFunc](https://justcoding121.github.io/Titanium-Web-Proxy/docs/api/Titanium.Web.Proxy.ProxyServer.html)
A callback to provide authentication credentials for up stream proxy this proxy is using for HTTP(S) requests. User should return the ExternalProxy object with valid credentials.

Declaration
public Func> GetCustomUpStreamProxyFunc { get; set; }
Property Value
Type    Description
Func>